How do I connect to a websocket server to a private channel from postman with laravel tokens?
I need to connect to a private channel in postman from the client side it works normal I can connect but I want to connect in postman now I know that it is necessary to be auth so I had the idea of obtwner a token through the enpoint broadcasting /auth but when I put it in the request of connection to channel I get unauthorized connection so there I saw that it can be an issue the lifetime of the tokens for the auth but how can I extend the lifetime of the tokens
I already tried that the postman put the token but he tells me that the connection is not authorized even though the token has come out a few seconds on the side of my frontend that is with next and udo laravel echo works normal auth ago but in postman putting the token not before by the way I am in laravel 11 and I am trying to do it with reverb
